# Undefined property: WP_Error:: $name

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone help me with this please? Trying to use the event-type as the name of the event but it's throwing the error in the title

```php
if (empty($_POST['_tmem_event_name'])){
    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification
    $_POST['_tmem_event_name'] = get_term(
        sanitize_text_field(
            wp_unslash(empty($_POST['tmem_event_type']))
        ),
        'event-types'
    )->name;
    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification
}
```

Comment: `wp_unslash(empty($_POST['tmem_event_type']))` <- why `empty()` here? It returns a Boolean

Comment: Literally have no idea... removing it fixed it though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a more specific answer, the `empty()` call is the underlying problem. `empty()` checks if the provided variable (`$_POST['term_event_type']` in this example) is empty and returns a `true` or `false` value. I suspect the intent here was something like this:

```php
// phpcs:disable WordPress.Security.NonceVerification
// phpcs:disable WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride
if ( empty( $_POST['_tmem_event_name'] ) ) {
    $post       = wp_unslash( $_POST );
    $event_type = ! empty( $post['tmem_event_type'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $post['tmem_event_type'] ) : false;

    if ( $event_type ) {
        $post['_tmem_event_name'] = get_term(
            $event_type,
            'event-types'
        )->name;
    }
}
// phpcs:enable WordPress.Security.NonceVerification
// phpcs:enable WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride
```

Since you're including a phpcs ignore line, I'll assume you're hoping to stick with a coding standard - you'll also likely be getting an error about overriding global variables. I disabled it for you. However, you really shouldn't be disabling either of those - they exist for a reason and are pretty simple to fix. Happy to help if you need it.